# Low performance reduceByKey() in Spark

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

I am writing a program on Spark, which I just do the aggregate by the key. The program is pretty simple. My input data is only 2GB, running on a multi-core server (8cores, 32GB RAM) with the setting local[2]. That is using two cores for parallelization. However, I found that the performance is pretty bad. It almost takes two hours to complete. I am using KryoSerializer. I guess it might be caused by Serializer. How to solve this problem?

```
  val dataPoints = SparkContextManager.textFile(dataLocation)
        .map(x => {
            val delimited = x.split(",")
            (delimited(ColumnIndices.HOME_ID_COLUMN).toLong, 
                delimited(ColumnIndices.USAGE_READING_COLUMN).toDouble)
        })

def process(step: Int): Array[(Long, List[Double])] = {
  val resultRDD = new PairRDDFunctions(dataPoints.map(x =>(x._1, List[Double](x._2))))
  resultRDD.reduceByKey((x, y) => x++y).collect()
}
```

The output will be:

```
1, [1, 3, 13, 21, ..., 111] // The size of list is about 4000
2, [24,34,65, 24, ..., 245]
....
```

Comment: Lower performance compared to what?

Comment: I mean it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Where do dataPoints come from? nothing in the code snippet about that. Perhaps your reducing functions are going through your whole data many times (once for every key?) That would explain why it takes so long.

Comment: Hi, Ashalynd, I have added the code snippet of dataPoints. It reads data from csv file, and split by delimiter ",". I cannot see why it goes through the whole data set for many times . Could you give more details? thanks

Comment: HI, Ashalynd, you are right. For every key, it has to go through the whole data data. But, it is what reduceByKey does. How could I improve it? thanks

Comment: Josh Rosen is correct, use the built in groupByKey.  This probably optimizes the `++` using `Iterator`s and is thus O(1), but your operation on `List`s is O(`y.size`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write a Spark job that groups together values that are associated with the same key.  PairRDDFunctions has a `groupByKey` operation that does this.  Spark's implementation of `groupByKey` takes advantage of several performance optimizations to create fewer temporary objects and shuffle less data over the network (since each value won't be wrapped in a `List`).

If you import Spark's implicit conversions, using

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

then you won't need to manually wrap your mapped RDD with `PairRDDFunctions` in order to access functions like `groupByKey`.  This doesn't have a performance impact and makes large Spark programs significantly easier to read.

Using `groupByKey`, I think your `process` function can be rewritten as

```
def process(step: Int): Array[(Long, Seq[Double])] = {
  dataPoints.groupByKey().collect()
}
```

I'd also consider increasing the degree of parallelism: both `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey` take an optional `numTasks` argument that controls the number of reducers; by default, Spark uses only 8 parallel tasks for `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey`.  This is described in the [Spark Scala Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html), as well as in the [Scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

Comment: Not agree, The DataBricks write a ebook about spark best practices, and at first it says Avoid groupByKey, just use reduceByKey, see it at: http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Answer (score 3):

For the code line:

```
resultRDD.reduceByKey((x, y) => x++y).collect()
```

reduceByKey(func, [numTasks]) could receive a second parameter

reference the official doc:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections

> When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, V)
>   pairs where the values for each key are aggregated using the given
>   reduce function func, which must be of type (V,V) => V. Like in
>   groupByKey, the number of reduce tasks is configurable through an
>   optional second argument.

**specific the numTasks to re-partition before shuffle to enhance shuffle MR performance.**

the @Josh Rosen is wrong. using reduceByKey may better than groupByKey,pls reference the doc

> When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs, returns a dataset of (K, Iterable) pairs. 
>   Note: If you are grouping in order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each key, using reduceByKey or aggregateByKey will yield much better performance. 
>   Note: By default, the level of parallelism in the output depends on the number of partitions of the parent RDD. You can pass an optional numTasks argument to set a different number of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Josh explains how to make it faster (and more readable) by refactoring to:

```
def process(): Array[(Long, List[Double])] = dataPoints.groupByKey().collect()
```

Note, you don't use `step`, so don't pass it.  Now the reason *why* it should be faster is because your calling `x ++ y` on `Seq` which is `O(x.size)`, but the `reduceByKey` function will under the hood be concatenating on `Iterator` which is `O(1)`.  This means if you have more partitions than you have keys, you'll be performing unnecessary `Seq` concatenations.

If you have 8 cores, aim for 16 - 32 partitions (2 - 4 tasks per CPU).

Now another thing that could be optimized is your string splitting, if the indexes of the `delimeted` you are interested in are << the total number of `,`s then you are unnecessarily splitting the tail end of the string.  For example, if you want indexes 0 and 4, and your string has 100 fields, then you'll get a bit of a speed up by not processing the tail 95 fields (this speed up will be more noticeable for cached RDDs).